# IMAPInputStream cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart

Tags: java, maven, email, jboss, jakarta-mail

I know people already asked this question but my problem is different...
I'm just trying to download attachments from an email, it is working when I execute "java -jar myproject.jar" on Windows using this code :

```
Object obj = message.getContent();
if (!(obj instanceof Multipart)) {
        String message1 = "This Message is not a multipart message!";
}
else {
        Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
        ...
}
```

But when I deploy this jar on Jboss 7 I got this error :

```
com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart
```

That return to me message1 : "This Message is not a multipart message!", I really don't understand why...

I use :
activation-1.1.jar/
javax.mail-1.5.2.jar/
JDK 1.6 (the Jboss is configured with this JDK and I can't change it, this is not my own server)

Thank you for your help

Comment: JBoss should include JavaMail (although an older version) so you shouldn't need to include those jar files in your application.  These conflicting jar files can cause the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Hi Bill and thank you for answer! It doesn't work... This jar really need those libraries...

Comment: Details, please.  What version of JBoss?  How exactly does your app fail without those jar files?  Note that even in the worst case you should be able to remove the activation jar file since it's included in JDK 1.6.  Also, try putting the JavaMail jar file in the JBoss lib directory instead of in your application.

Comment: JBoss version is 7.2.0 and I can find Javax.mail library ! Unfortunatly, I don't know how I have to connect lib JAR on JBoss to my JAR file...

Comment: What do you mean by "connect"?  Are you having trouble compiling your program?  Or are you having trouble running your program after it is compiled and packaged?  You'll need access to the JavaMail jar file (or the javaee.jar file) when compiling your program, but you don't need to include it in your application package (e.g., war file).  Exactly how are you building and packaging your application?

Comment: I have trouble running my program after it s compiled and packaged. When I execute my JAR on windows 7 there is no problem but when I execute this same JAR on the jboss server (jar's status is "deployed") I got this error. Thank you for your disponibility Bill
Right click > Export > Runnable JAR file > Package required library (...) (I also tested with "Extract required library...")

Comment: If you're creating a jar file (as opposed to, e.g., a war file), then I have no idea what's in that jar file or how JBoss is running it.  You probably need a JBoss expert to figure out what you're doing wrong.  Sorry.